# Recommendations on Lua Interpreter for Java

Tags: java, lua

I have a gui application written in java that requires the use of the lua scripting language. I looked at LuaJava but it seems to be giving me problems. Can you recommend a good lua interpreter for java, preferably a pure java implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LuaJ](http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html) is a good option however it is very poorly documented. Nevertheless I got it to work and hooked up additional libraries to get the functionality I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The only other Lua binding for Java I know is [JNLua](http://www.naef.com/jnlua/) (Java Native Lua). I have no experience with it, so I can't tell you anything about stability.

What kind of problems are you having with LuaJava?

Comment: Three that I have noticed so far. Program just exits when lua goes into panic mode. When I try to call a function, the program does not actually call the lua function until the application quits. Bad documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Kahlua](http://code.google.com/p/kahlua/) I've heard plenty of good things about it.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have been using LuaJ for the last month and while the documentation is indeed terrible the API itself is very flexible.

The source is open so you can study it yourself and (well at least that's how it works for me) eventually have a better understanding then I think you'd accomplish with documentation.

Also what is your problem with LuaJava? It's pretty easy to use, I've only had problems with it when I wanted to prepare my LuaValues in Java and then use them in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking at Lua interpreters, so thought I'd add this to this question for posterity: http://code.google.com/p/jillcode/ appears to be a pretty decent, pure Java Lua implementation.